# Unable to retrieve a custom field from Product2 in a LWC built of the B2B Commerce store front

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, b2b-commerce, ui-api, product2

I have built a LWC designed for B2B Commerce store Product Details page. I need to retrieve a custom field I have added to the product2 object in order to pass this to an iframe as a reference. To do this I have created this simple button component to extract the field and then redirect to the page where I will place the iframe. No matter what I do I cannot get the getrecord to return the Id and I keep getting the following message in the web page console:-

[{errorCode: "NOT_FOUND", message: "The requested resource does not exist"}]
0
:
{errorCode: "NOT_FOUND", message: "The requested resource does not exist"}
errorCode
:
"NOT_FOUND"
message
:
"The requested resource does not exist"

I am using getRecord and then using the @wire approach to try and retrieve the field but consistently getting
﻿
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ().

I have checked that the ID I am passing is correct, even if I pass the actual Id in directly in '' I get the same errors . All documentation I can find says this is the way to approach the problem. Nothing in the documentation mentions any restriction on Product2 or B2B Commerce so assume this approach is correct. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

.JS

```
import {LightningElement,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
const FIELDS = ['Product2.Name', 'Product2.Editor_Product_Aug_ID__c'];
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { CurrentPageReference, NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';


export default class Design_Button extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
     error;
     productname='-';
     editorprodid='-';
    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS})
    wireRec({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        } else if (data) {
            this.productname = data.fields.Name.value;
            this.editorprodid = data.fields.Editor_Product_Aug_ID__c.value;
        }
    }

andleButtonClick() {
        
        console.log('THIS RECORD NAME');
        console.log(this.productname);

        console.log('THIS Editor ID');
        console.log(this.editorprodid);


        console.log(THIS RECORD ID);
        console.log(this.recordId);


        const variableValue = 'Some Value'; // Set the desired variable value
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
             type: 'standard__webPage',
             attributes: {
                 url: '/mydesign' 
             }
         });
    }
}
```

HTML - Setting label to recordId to check its the right ID

```
<template>
    <lightning-button label={recordId} onclick={handleButtonClick}>  </lightning-button> 
</template>
```

Meta

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
 <targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Page_Layout</target>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Theme_Layout</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage,  lightning__HomePage, lightning__RecordPage,lightningCommunity__Default">
        
        <property
        name="recordId"
        label="record ID"
        type="String"
        default="{!recordId}"
        description="The record ID of the product"/>
       </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>

</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: I solved this. It was due to sharing rules. Needed to go to product Org Wide defaults and change from private.